# Ordering strings that contain numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column named `MR` which is a varchar. When I run a query with an `ORDER BY` it doesn't seem to be ordered correctly.

```
select MR, LName, FName from users 
  where MR between 'MR20001' and 'MR20002' 
  order by MR
```

Results:

```
MR20001   | LINA  | MARY
MR200011  | TEST  | CASE
MR20002   | KO    | MIKE
```

Why does `MR200011` show before `MR20002`?

Comment: `...which is a varchar` ____ what? 32? 255? MAX?

Comment: I have rolled back your question to the way it was originally.  Once you have accepted an answer, changing the content of the question (so as to make the answer incorrect) is not a good practice.  Besides, you have re-asked the question here (with the extra information): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14497692/how-do-i-sort-a-varchar-with-numbers-and-letters-without-a-specific-format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try casting it,

```
select MR, LName, FName 
from users 
where MR between 'MR20001' and 'MR20002' 
order by CAST(REPLACE(MR, 'MR', '') AS INT)
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ae729/1)

Answer (score 5):

Because `MR` is a string, and - for example - `24` sorts lower than `3` since it does not care about the numeric value. This would be like sorting `Smith` before `Azlea` because `z` > `m`.

If you want to treat just the number as a number, then perhaps don't store the `MR` prefix. Based on the column name this seems completely redundant. Why not store the numeric portion alone as an `INT` and create a view that appends the `'MR'` at runtime? You can easily do this without really affecting the app (add an instead of trigger if you can't control insert/update operations via a stored procedure):

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.users_appended
AS
    SELECT MR = 'MR' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), MR), 
        MRSort = MR --, ... other columns ...
      FROM dbo.users;
GO

SELECT MR, other columns
  FROM dbo.users_appended
  ORDER BY MRSort;
```

If you can't change the schema, you can say:

```
ORDER BY CONVERT(BIGINT, SUBSTRING(MR, 3, 25));
```

But I really don't think you should have `MR` stored in there at all. If you can't change this then maybe consider a view or a computed column that pulls out the numeric part of the string. You can even index a computed column if you are going to commonly order in only one direction.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.users ADD MRNumber
  AS (CONVERT(BIGINT, SUBSTRING(MR, 3, 25))) PERSISTED;

CREATE INDEX ix_mrnumber ON dbo.users(MRNumber);
```

You will have to test if the work required to maintain the computed column and the index are justified by the difference this makes to the query.

A view would be similar, but you wouldn't gain any efficiencies from an index:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.users_extended
AS
  SELECT MR, ..., MRNumber = CONVERT(BIGINT, SUBSTRING(MR, 3, 25));
GO

SELECT MR, ... 
  FROM dbo.users_extended
  ORDER BY MRNumber;
```

---

As for using `LEN` instead, be careful. While it is simpler code, it is not necessarily more efficient. On my system I created two tables with a wide distribution of values:

```
SELECT 'MR'+RTRIM(ABS(object_id)) AS MR 
  INTO dbo.flab 
  FROM sys.all_objects -- 2096 rows

SELECT 'MR'+RTRIM(ABS(s1.object_id)) AS MR 
  INTO dbo.mort 
  FROM sys.all_objects AS s1
  CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects AS s2; -- 4397409 rows
```

Now, testing simple queries like this:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.flab ORDER BY LEN(MR), MR;
SELECT * FROM dbo.flab ORDER BY CONVERT(BIGINT, SUBSTRING(MR, 3, 25));
SELECT * FROM dbo.mort ORDER BY LEN(MR), MR;
SELECT * FROM dbo.mort ORDER BY CONVERT(BIGINT, SUBSTRING(MR, 3, 25));
```

Results on a heap (pay close attention to duration and CPU, in spite of the nonsense SQL Server spits out in terms of estimated cost):

[image]

And with a clustered index on `MR`:

[image]

I've also changed all my calculations to `BIGINT` to avoid any potential danger that the substring is more than 12 characters (and still avoids an expensive - yes, expensive - `LEN()`). Note that the estimated costs are 50/50 and the duration differences are about the same if `INT` is used instead of `BIGINT` (assuming that it is safe to use `INT` - which I think is a safe assumption since the accepted answer would have failed if there were any larger values).

Comment: Aaron, what program/plug-in do you use to get cost of the queries as on the screenshots? I use system views for this but work with them is not very convenient. Thank you.

Comment: @Igor [SQL Sentry Plan Explorer](http://sqlsentry.net/plan-explorer/sql-server-query-view.asp)

Comment: @AaronBertrand what if the format of the MR column is not uniformed? What I mean to say is that if there is an additional entry with an 08-4567814 as MR. I can't use the substring in that case.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid all the expensive casting and replacing you can use this as an alternative:

```
select MR, LName, FName 
from Table1 
order by LEN(MR),MR
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ae729/6

Comment: You don't think `LEN` is free, do you? :-) There's a reason I used `12` instead of `LEN(MR)` in my `SUBSTRING` definitions...

Comment: While LEN certainly isn't free, LEN is faster than CONVERT(SUBSTRING()). Also, you don't know that the underlying number is never more than 10 digits, so hard-coding a 12 is very dangerous.

Comment: I think `INT` is a reasonable assumption, and no `INT` can be stored with > 10 digits. If it's `BIGINT` that's easy enough to fix. Also you'll notice that my suggestions involved more than just `CONVERT(SUBSTRING())` at runtime...

Comment: MR most likely stands for medical record number and as such is often more than 10 digits. Your suggestion involves adding a computed column that causes more IO and a index that could turn out useless when to may rows are included by the where clause. So I am still not sure where you see an advantage in your solution.  --  All in all I am not certain why you are fighting so hard here. I did not in any way attack you.

Comment: I am simply questioning your assertion that your solution is less expensive than the others. I'll add some info to my answer to show why I believe it is actually more expensive.

Comment: Also, if the persisted computed column and the index turn out to be indeed useful, `LEN()` can also be persisted as computed column and indexed and that it would be again faster than your `CONVERT(SUBSTRING())`

Comment: Please demonstrate how `LEN()` is faster than `CONVERT(SUBSTRING())`, as I seem to have done the opposite. If you're going to discredit other answers please have some data to back it up.